# How to store form data before redirecting to another page

Tags: asp-classic

I have a registration form, the form is sending to a third party payment page. Right now I want to insert the form data to a database before it goes to the third party payment page which I have no access to it. I am thinking to create a page, insert the data to my database and then redirect it to the payment page. There are a lot of variables need to be passed to the payment page, in stead of passing the variables in  querystring, is there any better way to do it? TIA

Comment: Is the original form submitting its data with `GET` or `POST` method ?

Answer (score 0):

Its always advisable to pass sensitive data via POST (instead of GET/querystring) [Click here to learn more about Get vs. Post forms in classic ASP!](http://www.w3schools.com/asp/asp_inputforms.asp)

Registration.asp - this page collects information from user using forms and submits data to add.asp

Add.asp - This page communicates with your database and validates user (exp- sends error message if username is already taken) then redirects to the payment page.

pay.asp - This is the payment page...